# perf not working for some commands?

Tags: android, perf, monkey

I'd like to use perf to profile the monkey command on Android, but I
got stuck with this.

Normally, when I run following:

```
  monkey -v -p com.google.android.youtube 500

  -it works (it generates 500 user events for youtube)
```

BUT, when I want to get the perf stat of it as follows:

```
  perf stat monkey -v -p com.google.android.youtube 500
```

I get:

```
 monkey: No such file or directory
 Terminated
```

monkey is a command, not a file nor a directory. Why am I getting
this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.
David

Comment: What is the result of a simple command like "perf stat ls"?
Which devices do you use?

Comment: simple commands such as 'ls' work fine. Performance counter stats for 'ls':

           5.096439  task-clock-msecs         #      0.142 CPUs 
                101  context-switches         #      0.020 M/sec
                  0  CPU-migrations           #      0.000 M/sec
                147  page-faults              #      0.029 M/sec
        0.035980222  seconds time elapsed..
Other commands do not work. Even on a computer. I'm using Galaxy S4 and Nexus 4.

Comment: That works for me with a Nexus 4 running Kitkat and perf version perf.3.0.8_android, with command: `$ perf stat monkey -v -p com.android.email 500`